# Confusion on learning of Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I have some questions about learning GANS, for example in the source code of the link below:

https://github.com/ImagingLab/Colorizing-with-GANs

in the file src/model I want to know if the generator and discriminator are trained at the same time or just only the generator is trained because I read in some papers that is not recommended to train the two networks (Discriminator a Generator) at the same time. If they are trained at the same time in this code which line can disable discriminator training?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how a generator is trained.  A generator *needs* feedback from the discriminator to define its loss function.  If you train the discriminator on your input data, and then begin to the train the generator, you are only training the generator to fool a fixed model.  I quite often have my discriminators slightly pre-trained just to try and provide "better" (really relative here) feedback to the generator, but never the other way around in my experience.

Comment: What you might have read about is a scenario when you use the discriminator, but don't update the weights when the generator updates.  That is fairly common to see, but again, it's not training the generator independent of a discriminator.

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit more, my initial comment may be slightly incorrect.  There are certainly variants of GANs that use fully pre-trained models as discriminators, but they make assumptions about the model to actually provide useful feedback, something that just any model may not account for.  If that is what you're interested in, something like the approach described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf), might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm new in GAN's, for this reason, I want some details about the concept, please for the shared code in the link, where can I find the lines which indicate the training step of the generator and the discriminator. Thank you in advance.